# How could I write this query in sequelize?

Tags: sequelize.js

Consider the following query:

`SELECT Film.FilmId FROM Films WHERE NOW() BETWEEN Film.StartDate AND Film.EndDate`

How could this query be written in sequelize? I know that using sequelize.fn('now') I should be able to get the `NOW()` mariadb function, but how should I tell sequelize to use this as the left operand of the where clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sequelize.where()` to generate a condition using the `sequelize.fn('NOW')` and then the [`Op.between` query operator](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators), passing in the columns for `Film.StartDate` and `Film.EndDate`.

See [Advanced queries with functions (not just columns)](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#advanced-queries-with-functions--not-just-columns-) in the documentation for more info.

```js
// get the Op query operators
const { Op } = require("sequelize");

// ... your code

// use await to find one Film, in an async function
const film = await Film.findOne({
  // just fetch the Film.FilmId
  attributes: ['FilmId'],
  where: {
    // create where condition for NOW()
    sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('NOW'), {
      // BETWEEN Film.StartDate AND Film.EndDate
      [Op.between]: [
        sequelize.col('Film.StartDate'), 
        sequelize.col('Film.EndDate')
      ],
    }),
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be a way around.

```
Film.findOne({
attributes: ['FilmId'],
where: {
    [Op.and]: [
        {
            StartDate: {
                [Op.lte]: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
            }
        },
        {
            EndDate: {
                [Op.gte]: sequelize.literal('NOW()')
            }
        }
    ]
}
});
```